# Python problems with importing txt files with different structure

Tags: python, csv, txt

Im new to python programming and I'm having an issue import a txt file that is comma seperated.

The current layout of the txt file is as follows:

1,2,3

,4,5,6,7

,8,9,10,11

1,2,3

,4,5,6,7

,8,9,10,11

etc etc

I would like to import it and load it in as a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

Headers

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

I've tried a lot but I just don't know what to google for.

Comment: Can you be more specific about 1) on what criteria the input is being stored. 2) in what format the pandas data structure should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it this way

```
import pandas as pd

with open("text.txt") as file:
    file = file.read()
data = file.split("\n")
data = [i for i in data if i != ""]
x = ["{}{}{}\n".format(*data) for i in range(len(data)//3)]
x = "".join(x)
with open('text2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("".join(x)+"\n")

df = pd.read_csv("text2.txt", header=None)
print(df)
```

out:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Space separated input of numbers is taken as -

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split())
```

To create a pandas series out of a list, with default indexing -

```
srs = pd.Series(lst)
```

To create a pandas dataframe out of a series -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(srs)
```

*(I will edit this post based on what exactly what you want, because it is not clear at the time.)*

Comment: I somehow found a solution, I added it as an answer but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the description :
You have to load text from the file and depending on leading commas of a line, concatenate them down to a row and then load it as a data frame.

You can load the data from file and concatenate the lines into rows depending on leading `,`

```py
with open("file.txt","r") as f:                                                                                   
    data=f.read()
data = data.replace("\n,",",")
```

Next, you can load the string as a dataframe

```py
import io import StringIO

data = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
```

P.S. : Without a `columns` parameter, the first row will be treated as the column name

Answer (score 0):

Somehow found the answer real quick suddenly, thanks for the help!

```
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_data = [' ,'.join(data[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
f = open('filename.txt', 'w')
for i in new_data:
   f.write("{}\n".format(i))
f.close()

df = pd.read_csv("filename.txt",header=None)
```